# Only load page when arriving from a URL - WordPRess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, elementor

How can I set a page (https://website.com/secret-page) to only be accessed or loaded when a visitor comes from a specific page or URL.

Example: Visitor loads /secret-page but did not arrive from /go-to-secret and therefore can't access the page and gets redirected to the /redirect page.

I was thinking of using .htaccess to achieve this but I have no idea what the code would be.

The website is built using WordPress and Elementor. Hopefully, someone can assist.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not set a session variable in the first site, and check for that in the second site?

Comment: Other than the unreliable and easily manipulatable HTTP referrer, there isn't much you can check on in .htaccess. A proper solution for this would use a PHP session.

Comment: @NicoHaase I've tried this: https://pastebin.com/SPPUeW73 but it did not work when adding the JS in <script> tags on the page using the HTML element widget.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use external links that contain relevant information

Comment: if it is internal, I would probably set a session. but if external links needs to work as well, then referer is my best guess, but I would not rely on the security of that.